# How to exclude {test} scoped dependencies from build?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have Java project build with maven that has some dependencies. One of such dependencies is another project (I have Eclipse workspace in mind) and it is only in `test` scope.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactid</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I build my projects using following command inside project root dir

```
mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

what I expected to happen it that maven would build project leaving test dependencies behind. However unresolved dependency exception is thrown (unresolved to my `test` scoped dependency). As I ran build command with `-X` option, I spoted following report in my project build plan:

```
[DEBUG] Dependencies (collect): []
[DEBUG] Dependencies (resolve): [compile, runtime, test]
[DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases)]
[DEBUG] Repositories (plugins)     : [central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases)]
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So despite skipping tests and even compiling them (`mvn clean compile` runs fine) maven tries to resolve test dependencies.

**How to exclude test dependencies from build plan dependency resolving step when skipping test executions?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short: you can't. At least not easily. `maven.test.skip` does not prevent the surefire:test mojo from running, it only configures the plugin to do nothing. (same for compile:testcompile).

Both mojos need dependency resolving of scope test (part of the mojo definition).

So, the only options of preventing those dependencies from being resolved would be either:

- Use a profile and rebind compiler:testCompile as well as surefire:test to non existing phases
- put all your test dependencies in a separate profile

However, both options are rather dirty.

So your best bet would be to install your dependent artifacts first (using `mvn install`) and simply accept the way maven resolves dependencies.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you.