# Skip compilation of integration test in maven project

Tags: maven, integration-testing

How do I skip the compilation of integration tests when installing a maven project?
I only found -DskipITs and -DskipTests but they only skip the execution, not the compilation.
I would like to remove the needed test dependencies.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>de.example.confluence</groupId>
  <artifactId>qspaRest</artifactId>
  <packaging>atlassian-plugin</packaging>
  <name>qspaRest</name>
  <version>3.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description>REST resources needed by the QSPA backend importer for
 * getting meta information from a space (name, description, homepage, permissions, ...)</description>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>/Users/example/git/qsparest/qsparest/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>/Users/example/git/qsparest/qsparest/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>/Users/example/git/qsparest/qsparest/target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>/Users/example/git/qsparest/qsparest/target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>/Users/example/git/qsparest/qsparest/src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>/Users/example/git/qsparest/qsparest/src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>

    <directory>/Users/example/git/qsparest/qsparest/target</directory>
<!--    <finalName>qspaRest-3.0.3-SNAPSHOT</finalName>-->
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.2</version>
        </plugin>

      <!-- For install:install-file-->
<!--
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install-file</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
-->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-rar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0-beta-8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0-beta-7</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1-alpha-2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
        <filesets>
            <!-- delete directories that will be generated when you 
                 start the develpment server/client in eclipse  
            -->
            <fileset>
                <directory>target</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </fileset>
        </filesets>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-confluence-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <allowGoogleTracking>false</allowGoogleTracking>
          <productVersion>${confluence.version}</productVersion>
          <productDataVersion>3.5</productDataVersion>
          <productDataPath>${basedir}/src/test/resources/generated-test-resources.zip</productDataPath>
          <instructions />
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </snapshots>
      <id>atlassian-public</id>
      <url>https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>atlassian-plugin-sdk</id>
      <url>file:///Users/example/Desktop/atlassian-plugin-sdk-3.9/repository</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </snapshots>
      <id>atlassian-public</id>
      <url>https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.4</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.6</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.jwebunit</groupId>
      <artifactId>jwebunit-htmlunit-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.atlassian.confluence.plugin</groupId>
      <artifactId>func-test</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.atlassian.confluence</groupId>
      <artifactId>confluence</artifactId>
      <version>${confluence.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.wink</groupId>
      <artifactId>wink-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.3-incubating</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

<!--
    <dependency>
      <groupId>de.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>qspaBackend</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
-->
<!-- TODO: There is no separate confluence artifact, so we depend on the complete backend at the moment
-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>de.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>qspaJiraModel</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>de.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>qspaConfluenceModel</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
<!--
-->
  </dependencies>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>/Users/example/git/qsparest/qsparest/target/site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
  <properties>
    <amps.version>3.9</amps.version>
    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
    <confluence.data.version>3.5</confluence.data.version>
    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
    <confluence.version>4.1.4</confluence.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>

    <!-- Settings for install:install-file-->
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <packaging>${project.packaging}</packaging>
    <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</file>
  </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to exclude {test} scoped dependencies from build?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22609534/how-to-exclude-test-scoped-dependencies-from-build)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` will skip all tests and also all test compilation, because it is accepted by the failsafe, surefire and compiler plugin. All other properties like `-DskipTests` will only skip the execution of the tests but the files are still compiled.